# container exited with code 100 while making mongodb container up

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

I am trying to making it up mongodb container but i am getting error

> Starting v2_mongodb ... done
>
> Starting rockmongo_v2 ... done
>
> Attaching to v2_mongodb, rockmongo_v2
>
> v2_mongodb      | Starting mongod...
>
> v2_mongodb exited with code 100

Here is the content of docker-compose.yml file and output of docker ps

```
 version: '2'
 services:
  v2_db:
    image: sameersbn/mongodb:latest
    container_name: "v2_mongodb"
    ports:
     - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
     - ./data/db:/data/db:rw
     - ./data/db:/var/lib/mongodb:rw
    environment:
     - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
    command: mongod --verbose --smallfiles  --dbpath=/data/db # --quiet
 rockmongo_v2:
  image: javierjeronimo/rockmongo:latest
  container_name: "rockmongo_v2"
  ports:
    - "27118:80"
  links:
    - v2_db:mongo
  depends_on:
    - v2_db
```

docker ps output

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                            COMMAND                CREATED       STATUS           PORTS                  NAMES
94794d6f3ff1  javierjeronimo/rockmongo:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'service…" 38 minutes ago   Up About a minute 0.0.0.0:27118->80/tcp rockmongo_v2
bd4ed92796db sameersbn/mongodb:latest          "/sbin/entrypoint.sh…" 38 minutes ago   Exited (100) About a minute ago       v2_mongodb
```

I am not able to get the clue what can be the possible cause of above error?

Answer (score 3):

List your volume links:
docker volumes ls

Delete the volumes: (In my case this freed up about 29.35 Gig)
docker volumes prune

Comment: Yes, I had the 100 error code after upgrading the mongo image version.